# Hit testing on a MapView, Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, hittest

I hava a MapView and I define a Rect. Touching the map I compare the coordinates to detect whether the rect is touched or not. But it does not work

```
RectF hitTestRecr = new RectF();
hitTestRecr.set(0,100,0,100);
hitTestRecr.offset(0,0);

if (hitTestRecr.contains(event.getX(),event.getY())) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

I always get no hit

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your RectF is 0 wide and 0 tall.

```
set(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

I think what you want is

```
hitTestRecr.set(0,0,100,100);
```